# A few months ago I created and published my GDPR consent message and also updated my apps but again a warning started to show in my AdMob Account

Tags: android, flutter, admob, adsense

This is what it looks like -
[image]

"You confirmed that you'll create and publish your GDPR consent message by 16 January 2024. Make sure that you use a certified consent management platform (CMP) that integrates with the TCF. If you miss the deadline, we'll attempt to publish a default consent message for you using an interstitial or app open ad unit, when possible."

My published GDPR consent message -
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This warning is a general one, all of us got it, do not worry about it. even if you fixed everything you will receive it.

Comment: yeah, we can sleep fine :)

Comment: Is there an official blog/link/documentation page where it says we don't need to worry about it even if we fixed everything? If so could you update your answer with it I'm would be very interested what is the official statement to that warning. Thanks.